# How to save and load tensors in the best way when you have very large data

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am facing a question that I would need more support from the community.
For example, I want to make a recommendation system. I turn every part of the product into an embed.

```
product_url_embedding: Embedding = self.get_product_url_embedding(product_url=product.product_url)
        categories_embedding: Embedding = self.get_categories_embedding(categories=product.categories)
        price_embedding: Embedding = self.get_price_embedding(price=product.price)
```

All good so far. But for example, I need products when I make recommendations in this form so that I can calculate the similarities with the user's actions.
My question is:
How could I keep this data so that I don't have a big load?
For example, I now save each embed in the database as a `BYTEA`, but this is expensive in terms of performance..
Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just use `torch.save`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use in-memory vector database [chroma] or other vector db for improving performance of comparing embedding pairs[1](https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma)

you can create db and choose the similarity metric(for example cosine)

```
 collection = client.create_collection(
        name="collection_name",
        metadata={"hnsw:space": "cosine"} 
    )
```

and then search top similar object

```
collection.query(
    query_embeddings=[[11.1, 12.1, 13.1],[1.1, 2.3, 3.2], ...],
    n_results=10,
    where={"metadata_field": "is_equal_to_this"},
    where_document={"$contains":"search_string"}
)
```